# How to make buttons retain their size in FXML

Tags: java, css, button, javafx, fxml

So the Button look normal when the program starts but If the decrease the size the window with my cursor horizontally or vertically, the buttons shrink to a smaller size.

**Code**

**FXML File**

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.net.URL?>

<VBox fx:id="OptionMenuLayout" alignment="TOP_CENTER" spacing="15"   prefWidth="1366"  prefHeight="768"   xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" fx:controller="millionairetriviagame.OptionscreenController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@BackgroundImages.css" />
    </stylesheets>
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@ButtonLayout.css" />
    </stylesheets>
    <children>
        <ImageView fitHeight="300" fitWidth="300" smooth="true" >
            <image>
                <Image url="@ImageFiles/MillionaireLogo1.png" />
            </image>
        </ImageView>
        <Label style="-fx-font-style: Italic;" text="Click to Change the Background Color" textFill="white">
            <font>
                <javafx.scene.text.Font name="sans-serif" size="20" />  
            </font>
        </Label>      
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="200">
            <children>
                <Button id="SmallBlueBackground1"  fx:id="optionButton1" onAction="#changeBackgroundScreen" prefHeight="50" prefWidth="80" />
                <Button id="SmallBlueBackground2" fx:id="optionButton2" onAction="#changeBackgroundScreen" prefHeight="50" prefWidth="80" />
                <Button id="SmallBlueBackground3" fx:id="optionButton3" onAction="#changeBackgroundScreen" prefHeight="50" prefWidth="80" />
            </children>
        </HBox>     
        <Region prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
        <HBox alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" spacing="10">
            <children>
                <Button fx:id="backToMain" onAction="#goToTheMainMenu" prefHeight="30" prefWidth="200" id="ButtonLayout" text="Back to the Main Menu"> 
                    <shape>
                        <javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle arcHeight="30" arcWidth="30" height="30" width="200" />  
                    </shape>
                </Button>
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

**Here is a screenshot: Note that I resized the screen with my cursor to show this as this is right not the size of the screen**

[image]

As you can see, the buttons are not their regular size.

**Here is the CSS file(if need be) associated with the 3 main buttons that you see in the screenshot**

```
#BlueBackground1
{
    -fx-background-image: url("/millionairetriviagame/ImageFiles/BlueBackgroundColor.jpg");
    -fx-smooth: true;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
}

#BlueBackground2
{
    -fx-background-image: url("/millionairetriviagame/ImageFiles/BlueBackgroundColor2.jpg");
    -fx-smooth: true;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
}

#BlueBackground3
{
    -fx-background-image: url("/millionairetriviagame/ImageFiles/BlueBackgroundColor3.jpg");
    -fx-smooth: true;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
}

#SmallBlueBackground1
{
    -fx-background-image: url("/millionairetriviagame/ImageFiles/BlueBackgroundColor.jpg");
    -fx-background-repeat: stretch;   
    -fx-background-size: 80 50;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0, 0, 0;
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-width: 3;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, black, 5, 0.5, 0, 0); 
}

#SmallBlueBackground2
{
    -fx-background-image: url("/millionairetriviagame/ImageFiles/BlueBackgroundColor2.jpg");
    -fx-background-repeat: stretch;   
    -fx-background-size: 80 50;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0, 0, 0;
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-width: 3;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, black, 5, 0.5, 0, 0); 
}

#SmallBlueBackground3
{
    -fx-background-image: url("/millionairetriviagame/ImageFiles/BlueBackgroundColor3.jpg");
    -fx-background-repeat: stretch;   
    -fx-background-size: 80 50;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0, 0, 0;
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-width: 3;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, black, 5, 0.5, 0, 0); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have dynamic dimensions you shouldn't use min/pref/max size. Instead you should use proper layout containers. For your example you could use e. g. a

- VBox for the entire screen
- a top and a bottom Stackpane in that VBox
- a GridPane in the bottom Stackpane for the buttons

and let the button dimensions be computed.

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <StackPane VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <StackPane VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <GridPane hgap="10.0" vgap="10.0">
              <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <RowConstraints vgrow="ALWAYS" />
              </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                  <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                  <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
               </children>
               <StackPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </StackPane.margin>
            </GridPane>
         </children>
      </StackPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

*Note: The "1.7976931348623157E308" values are MAX_VALUE in scene builder.*

Answer (score 0):

Set min size on the button like pref size. That should work.

@edit: And you could set the resizable attribute to false